# How to execute a Gradle task once at the end of subproject tasks

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I am working with the following project structure

```
Project
|-Subproject1
|-Subproject2
|build.gradle
|settings.gradle
```

The submodules are included in the `settings.gradle` and configured in the `build.gradle` of the root project.

I have 3 tasks to do

1. `build` (every subproject has this)
2. `deploy` (this is a packaging mechanism for every subproject needs to work on its own)
3. `finalizeDeployment` (this needs to be invoked only once)

I want to be able to call

`$gradle deploy` <- all subprojects get deployed and finalize gets called **once** at the end

`$gradle Subproject1:deploy` <- Subproject1 gets deployed and finalize gets called

build.gradle

```groovy
configure(subprojects) {

    task build <<{
        println "Do Build "+ project.name
    }

    task deploy(dependsOn:build){
        println 'deploy '+project.name

        doLast{
            finalizeDeployment.execute()
        }
    }
}

task finalizeDeployment{

    dependsOn subprojects.deploy

    doLast{
        println 'Finalize Deployment'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works the following way

```groovy
configure(subprojects) {

    task build << {
        println "Do Build " + project.name
    }

    task deployPrepare(dependsOn: build)<<{
            println 'deploy ' + project.name
    }

    task deployFinalize(dependsOn: deployPrepare)<<{
        parent.deployFinalize.execute()
    }
}

task deployFinalize {

    doLast {
        println 'Finalize Deployment'
    }
}

deployFinalize.dependsOn(subprojects.deployPrepare)
```

The Console output for `gradle subproject1:deployFinalize` is:

```
Do Build subproject1
deploy subproject1
Finalize Deployment
```

The Console output for `gradle deployFinalize` is:

```
Do Build subproject1
deploy subproject1
Do Build subproject2
deploy subproject2
Finalize Deployment
```

Comment: I like the work around for the solution. However, (due to the current state of Gradle) the calling logic is still a little confusing since you need to call deployFinalize in order for the eponymous task to be run last (intuitively one might expect it to run first).

Comment: @ZenBalance what's the reason you're expecting it to run first? Isn't the last line making sure it's run last (it depends on all subprojects' deployment tasks).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can get the same functionality with dependencies without needing to use parent.deployFinalize.execute().

Where I work we use:

```groovy
subprojects {

   task dist(type: Copy, dependsOn: assemble) {
       ...
   }
}

task dist
dist.dependsOn subprojects.dist

task finalizeDist(dependsOn : subprojects.dist) {
    ...
}
dist.dependsOn finalizeDist
```

Comment: How does this force `finalizeDist` to execute if the command line is: `gradle subproject1:dist`?