# How to find Gradle task that creates some specific output?

Tags: gradle

I'd like to create a task that would take as input the `@OutputFile` of some other task. I know the output file that needs to be taken as input but not the task that creates that output file so that the task that uses the output can `dependsOn` the output creator. How do I find which task creates that output?

More concretely:

- `$unknownTask` creates `someKnownOutput`
- `newTask` uses `someKnownOutput`
- `newTask` would like to `dependsOn $unknownTask`

How can the value of `$unknownTask` be found?

Comment: By "output" do you mean console output or a file?  If the task marks the file as a TaskOutput, you can probably gain insight by running with -i or -d (I imagine Gradle logs such things).  If it doesn't, then Gradle has no way of knowing what the task is doing internally, so you'd kind of be on your own.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear (even though I thought the description under `More concretely` was pretty clear).

Comment: The regular approach would be to understand how Gradle or the used plugins work to get the neccessary insights. Is the name of the file constant or does it follow a pattern?

Comment: And how does your `build.gradle` file look like?

Comment: For this specific instance, I've found what creates that file. Since this isn't the first time I've run into this issue, I was hoping there's a more general solution to this general problem. I think I'm getting close to codifying it, though, and will post the answer when I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should print out the tasks whose output is `thisIsTheOne`:

```
task findTaskCreatingSpecificOutput() {
  doLast {
    subprojects { subproject ->
      subproject.tasks.findAll { task ->
        task.outputs.getFiles().getFiles().findAll { output ->
          output == 'thisIsTheOne'
        }
      }.flatten().each { println it }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16035083)

Comment: That's an answer to my question.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. Without any text it's a bit hard to tell, tough, especially since someone asked "how does your build.gradle file look like?" in the comments  ;-)

Comment: Text added. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: How do you ensure that this task runs after all the other tasks to make sure that the outputs are populated?

Comment: @mjaggard, does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880461/how-to-make-tasks-execute-one-after-another address your question?

Comment: Sort of. I solved it by making this task depend on the task I was debugging at the time - but there doesn't seem to be a general way to run a task last.

Comment: If https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166605/how-to-execute-a-gradle-task-once-at-the-end-of-subproject-tasks doesn't help in your scenario, try creating a new question.